# Space efficient map/dictionary/database with URI/URL keys

Tags: database, url, dictionary, uri

I'm looking for a space-efficient key-value mapping/dictionary/database which satisfies certain properties:

- **Format:** The keys will be represented by http(s) URIs. The values will be variable length binary data.
- **Size:** There will be 1-100 billion unique keys (average length 60-70 bytes). Values will initially only be a few tens of bytes but might eventually grow to tens of kilobytes in size (perhaps even more if I decide to store multiple versions). The total size of the data will be measured in terabytes or petabytes.
- **Hardware:** The data will have to be distributed across multiple machines. This distribution should ensure that all URIs from a particular domain end up on the same machine. Furthermore, data on a machine will have to be distributed between the RAM, SSD, and HDD according to how frequently it is accessed. Data will have to be shifted around as machines are added or removed from the cluster. Replication is not needed initially, but might be useful later.
- **Access patterns:** I need both sequential and (somewhat) random access to the data. The sequential access will be from a low-priority batch process that continually scans through the data. Throughput is much more important than latency in this case. Ideally, the iteration will proceed lexicographicaly (i.e. dictionary order). The random accesses arise from accessing the URIs in an HTML page, I expect that most of these will point to URIs from the same domain as the page and hence will be located on the same machine, while others will be located on different machines. I anticipate needing at most 100,000 to 1,000,000 in-memory random accesses per second. The data is not static. Reads will occur one or two orders of magnitude more often than writes.

Initially, the data will be composed of 100 million to 1 billion urls with several tens of bytes of data per url. It will be hosted on a small number of cheap commodity servers with 10-20GBs of RAM and several TBs of hard drives. In this case, most of the space will be taken up storing the keys and indexing information. For this reason, and because I have a tight budget, **I'm looking for something which will allow me to store this information in as little space as possible**. In particular, I'm hoping to **exploit the common prefixes** shared by many of the URIs. In this way, I believe it might be possible to store the keys and index in less space than the total length of the URIs.

I've looked at several traditional data structures (e.g. hash-maps, self-balancing trees (e.g. red-black, AVL, B), tries). Only the tries (with some tricks) seem to have the potential for reducing the size of the index and keys (all the others store the keys in addition to the index). The most promising option I've thought of is to split URIs into several components (e.g. example.org/a/b/c?d=e&f=g becomes something like [example, org, a, b, c, d=e, f=g]). The various components would each index a child in subsequent levels of a tree-like structure, kind of like a filesystem. This seems profitable as a lot of URIs share the same domain and directory prefix.

Unfortunately, I don't know much about the various database offerings. I understand that a lot of them use B-trees to index the data. As I understand it, the space required by the index and keys exceeds the total length of the URLs.

So, I would like to know if anyone can offer some guidance as to any data structures or databases that can exploit the redundancy in the URIs to save space. The other stuff is less important, but any help there would be appreciated too.

Thanks, and sorry for the verbosity ;)

Comment: depending on use, intended lifetime and quality requirements storing ip addresses instead of the schema portions of the http uris might be an option. this will have the additional benefit of constant length (32/128 bit for ipv4/6) for the prefix of your keys. partitioning of your dictionary respecting realms could be implemented using bit masks. the strong caveat is of course that the the mapping between ip and dns names is anything but static.